# ZIP file is of zero bytes, files are not copied

Tags: go

Zip file is of zero bytes though the file object is in the input is not null

```
func addFileToZip(zipWriter *zip.Writer, file *os.File) error {
    defer file.Close()
    fmt.Println("File name:", file.Name())
    fi, err := file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        // Could not obtain stat, handle error
    }
    fmt.Println("The file is %d bytes long", fi.Size())

    w1, err := zipWriter.Create(file.Name())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    copyFile, err := io.Copy(w1, file) // (dst, src
    fmt.Println("Copied file size:", copyFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error copying file to zip:", err)
    }
    return err
}
```

what am I missing ? any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to call `z1.Close()`!

Comment: Since the zip stream is buffered, you need to ensure any unwritten bytes are flushed. Your content must be small enough to fit into that buffer and is lost due to an unflushed buffered. To ensure flushing always call [Close()](https://pkg.go.dev/archive/zip#Writer.Close)